# Zend Framework 2 Hierarchy Semantics?

Tags: zend-framework2

I've been searching and trying to learn for ages but it just doesn't stick. There seems to be only 1 tutorial on Zend 2, and it's not very smart. Here we have a sample structure (and the tutorial proceeds with this application) http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/modules.html :

```
zf2-tutorial/
    /module
        /Album
            /config
            /src
                /Album
                    /Controller
                    /Form
                    /Model
            /view
                /album
                    /album
```

That's not cool - how do I know which album is which? In Zend 1 it made a lot of sense - you have modules, then you have controllers, and those controllers have actions.

Now I have a module called Album. is the `src/Album/...` a "single controller"? Would:

`zend1application/modules/album/albumcontroller.php` map to `zend2application/modules/album/src/album/controller/albumcontroller.php`? In that case, why are there 3 albums now? Like what happens if I change albumcontroller.php to indexcontroller.php? (I have been testing but there are so many changes it never sticks - I finally thought I should ask someone and if I know **why** I'll remember.

If I look at it a different way it seems the Album in `module/Album` and `module/Album/src/Album` should be the same - then why would we have it twice? Doesn't that just make room for error? Like why have a `src/album` folder? Why not put Controller, Form, and Model under `module/Album`?

Why is there a folder called Controller? There used to be a folder called **controllers** (plural, why singular now?) in a module before, that makes sense. But why is/are controller(s) inside a `src/Album` folder now?

Thank you for your time. I have tried to research but I think it's just too big absorb when (in my opinion) it seems so sparsely documented. Or, if someone could point me to a book like http://survivethedeepend.com/ but for ZF2, it'd be greatly apprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zend Framework 2 follows [PHPfigs PSR-0 Standards](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md). This means that the directory structure directly relates to the classname. But before i come close to that, let me explain the basic architecture.

First you have the `ModuleNAME`. Since the Module name needs to be unique, it only makes sense to map the Modulename to the `Namespace` of your model.

Inside the modules folder you have three sub-folders. One folder for configuration items named `config`. One folder for source-code files named `src` and one additional folder for the view files `view`

This separation is simply for overview. You separate configuration, view and sourcecode from another. It makes no sense to bunch them together and i guess you'd agree. This pretty much has been the same for ZF1, too.

The interesting part is the source-folder `src`. Earlier i mentioned about the `PSR-0` Standard. And this is the place where it comes into effect. By default the source-files for each module will be looked upon from the source-folder `src`. So whenever you have a class, it will be using PSR-0 Standards based off of the source-folder. Mewning: `My\Funky\Class` would be found within `src\My\Funky\Class.php`

And that's basically all there is to it. Controllers usually have a FQCN like `Mymodule\Controller\SomeController` so you will find this class inside `src\Mymodule\Controller\SomeController.php`

The main question arising could be: Why are the folders sometimes all `lowercase` and sometimes `ucfirst`. The answer, once again, is `PSR-Standards`. Classnames and/or Namespaces are supposed to begin with an `upperchar` character. And since path-names are `case-sensitive`, the folders need to match the classnames exactly!

**EDIT** Another nice read i've just stumbled upon is Rob Allens latest blogpost: [Thoughts on module directory structure](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/thoughts-on-module-directory-structure/). He explains how you can change the default setup quite easily to your likings.

Comment: That makes good sense. So the only immediate folder inside `src` should be the module name? And the fact `Controller`, `Model`, and `Form` is singular is just a quirk (quite annoying in fact)

Comment: Not really a quirk, when you consider your classnames. It'll be `Modulename\Controller\IndexController`. That's ONE Controller, so singular is only logical for the `\Controller`-Folder.

Comment: But isn't it technically a folder of controllers, like IndexController, MyOtherController, etc. Little fuss but just wondering why it changed from Zend 1 (most ZF1 setups I see have controllers plural). Likewise, we have multiple models and forms, all plural.

Comment: Reasoning is PSR-0, as mentioned above. Folder structure follows classnames. Classnames should be singular :)

Comment: Alright, I'm cool with that xD Thanks for the excellent answer!

Comment: @Raeki Added another link from Akrabat. It may interest you.